# Opacity in Polygons

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created a polygon with a .kml file at altitude to represent 3D airspace, and have set the opacity at 17%.  So far it looks great.  Then I created a path at altitude to represent a flight path through the airpace and set that opacity at 100%.  I can see the terrain through the polygon, but I cannot see the path through the polygon, even though the path is set to 100% opacity.  I would think that I should be able to see 100% opacity behind 17% opacity.  What gives?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies to polygons, but I presume it will work. Look into using

```
  <gx:drawOrder>
```

http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/draworder.html